# Highlight text at Quill editor without focus

Tags: angular, quill

I'm using angular and Quill editor.
I want to have the ability to select text at the quill editor and then type on a text label (other component), and that the text at the editor will remain selected while the focus is now on the text label.
the problem is that when I select a text at the quill editor and then try to type in a text label at other component I lose the focus and the text at the editor is not selected.

I tried to play with the event of OnFocus and OnBlur,
and I thought of using timeout.. still does not work